# Creating INSERT Statement

Tags: oracle

Having issues with an Insert Statement, can someone please assist me with my errors. I am getting error

```
ERROR at line 2: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
```

This is what I have so far, and thank you in advance.

```
SELECT GuestID, FirstName, LastName, Province;
FROM GUEST_JJ_9263
WHERE GuestID IS NULL OR FirstName IS NULL OR LastName IS NULL or City IS NULL OR Province IS NULL;
```

```
INSERT INTO GUEST_JJ_9263 (GuestID) VALUES (9999)
SELECT GuestID, FirstName ,LastName ,City ,Province
 FROM GUEST_JJ_9263
  WHERE GuestID IS NULL OR FirstName IS NULL OR LastName IS NULL or City IS NULL OR Province IS NULL;
ORDER BY LastName DESC, FirstName ASC;
```

I keep getting an error.

Comment: *`.. OR Province IS NULL; ..`* - excess `';'` char, must be removed. PS. reporting about an error always provide complete error message text.

Comment: My apologies, I am getting error "ERROR at line 2: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended."

Comment: Your DBMS is OracleDB, not MySQL. Nevertheless the source of your problem is the same - excess `;` which must be removed.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You actually want the semicolon at the end of the first line:

`INSERT INTO GUEST_JJ_9263 (GuestID) VALUES (9999);`

which will create a row in your table `GUEST_JJ_9263` with `GuestID` column populated with `9999`.

The next part will select out that row plus any others that meet the criteria.

If you are trying to duplicate the already-existing rows, you want:

`INSERT INTO GUEST_JJ_9263 SELECT GuestID, FirstName, LastName, City, Province FROM GUEST_JJ_9263 WHERE GuestID IS NULL  OR FirstName IS NULL  OR LastName IS NULL  OR City IS NULL  OR Province IS NULL;`